# casting to string of column for pyspark dataframe throws error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have pyspark dataframe with two columns with datatypes as

[('area', 'int'), ('customer_play_id', 'int')]

```
+----+----------------+
|area|customer_play_id|
+----+----------------+
| 100|        8606738 |
| 110|        8601843 |
| 130|        8602984 |
+----+----------------+
```

I want to cast column area to str using pyspark commands but I am getting error as below

I tried below

1. str(df['area']) : but it didnt change datatype to str
2. df.area.astype(str) : gave "TypeError: unexpected type: "
3. df['area'].cast(str) same as error above

Any help will be appreciated
I want datatype of area as string using pyspark dataframe operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can do any of these -

**Option1:**

```
df1 = df.select('*',df.area.cast("string"))
```

`select` - All the columns you want in df1 should be mentioned in select

**Option2:**

```
df1 = df.selectExpr("*","cast(area as string) AS new_area")
```

`selectExpr` - All the columns you want in df1 should be mentioned in selectExpr

**Option3:**

```
df1 = df.withColumn("new_area", df.area.cast("string"))
```

`withColumn` will add new column (additional to existing columns of df)

"*" in `select` and `selectExpr` represent all the columns.

Comment: but how will it be applied to complete df. What i mean is after running above command datatype gets changed but when i print df.dtypes, i get only one column and not the remaining

Comment: edited my answer. You need to assign it to a new dataframe.

Comment: yes, but after i assign it to dataframe, it reduced number of column to 1 which will be only area

Comment: You have to mention all the columns in select, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

use withColumn function to change the data type or values in the field in spark e.g. is show below:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = df.withColumn("area",F.col("area").cast("string"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use this UDF Function

```
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
tofloatfunc = udf(lambda x: x,FloatType())
changedTypedf = df.withColumn("Column_name", df["Column_name"].cast(FloatType()))
```